# Retrieve unique documents from elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

How to get all the unique documents from a index.Do i need to write the aggregation queries for all the fields of document. Can i get unique documents without writting the aggregation for each n every field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that with script :

```
    PUT test/doc/1 
{ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" }

 PUT test/doc/2 { "field1": "value2", "field2": "value3" } 

PUT test/doc/3 { "field1": "value1", "field2": "value3" } PUT test/doc/4 { "field1": "value3", "field2": "value4" }

 GET test/_search { "size": 0, "aggs": { "cardinality": { "cardinality": { "script": { "inline": "[ doc['field1'].value, doc['field2'].value ]" } } } } }
```

From [discuss elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cardinality-aggregation-on-several-fields/34519/2)